# get previous row value for computation when n is variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset of dates and maintenance qualifications.  I need to get the time since last maintenance touch.  I read about the `shift()` but my previous rows will be variable.  here is a sample dataset.

```
         Leg_ID SeqNum MX_IN_Local_Date_Time MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time RON ROD mxTouch mxTouchDate
1  19W-0001-001      1   2018-02-15 07:29:00    2018-02-15 08:14:00  NA  NA       0  1518682440
2  19W-0001-002      2   2018-02-15 09:34:00    2018-02-15 10:39:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
3  19W-0001-003      3   2018-02-15 12:07:00    2018-02-15 13:00:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
4  19W-0001-004      4   2018-02-15 14:36:00    2018-02-15 15:21:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
5  19W-0001-005      5   2018-02-15 18:03:00    2018-02-15 18:43:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
6  19W-0001-006      6   2018-02-15 20:59:00    2018-02-16 06:59:00   1  NA       1  1518764340
7  19W-0001-007      7   2018-02-16 09:40:00    2018-02-16 10:29:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
8  19W-0001-008      8   2018-02-16 12:59:00    2018-02-16 13:55:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
9  19W-0001-009      9   2018-02-16 16:28:00    2018-02-16 17:10:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
10 19W-0001-010     10   2018-02-16 19:45:00    2018-02-16 20:46:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
11 19W-0001-011     11   2018-02-16 21:54:00    2018-02-17 08:00:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
12 19W-0001-012     12   2018-02-17 09:23:00    2018-02-17 10:25:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
13 19W-0001-013     13   2018-02-17 14:58:00    2018-02-17 15:50:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
14 19W-0001-014     14   2018-02-17 18:26:00    2018-02-17 20:20:00  NA  NA      NA          NA
15 19W-0001-015     15   2018-02-17 23:00:00    2018-02-18 08:25:00   1  NA       1  1518942300
```

I know how to accomplish this in a loop, but I am trying to avoid loops in R.  Essentially what I am looking for is

```
If mxTouch = NA then MX_IN_Local_Date_time - previous mxTouchDate
```

My final output should be total minutes since the previous mxTouchDate.  Thanks for the help.

For clarification, here is an example of what I am looking for.

```
   date mxTouch sinceLastMxTouch
1     1       0                0
2     2      NA                1
3     3      NA                2
4     4       1                3
5     5      NA                1
6     6      NA                2
7     7      NA                3
8     8      NA                4
9     9       1                5
10   10      NA                1
```

When mxTouch == 0, sinceLastMxTouch = 0
When mxTouch == NA  or 1, sinceLastMXTouch = date - date when last mxTouch occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution using the `fill()` from the `{tidyr}` package.  I did use the `lag()` as well in a different way to complete the code. Here is my final working code.

```
mxStaSet <- add_column(mxStaSet, mxTouch = ifelse(mxStaSet$RON == 1 | 
                          mxStaSet$ROD == 1, 1,NA))
mxStaSet$mxTouch <- ifelse(mxStaSet$SeqNum == 1, 0, mxStaSet$mxTouch)

mxStaSet <- add_column(mxStaSet, mxTouchDate = 
                         ifelse(mxStaSet$mxTouch >= 0,
                                mxStaSet$MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time, NA))

mxStaSet <- mxStaSet %>% fill(mxTouchDate)

mxStaSet$mxTouchDate <- ifelse(mxStaSet$mxTouch == 0 | is.na(mxStaSet$mxTouch), 
                              mxStaSet$mxTouchDate, lag(mxStaSet$mxTouchDate))

mxStaSet$mxTouchDate <- as.integer(mxStaSet$MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time - 
                                 mxStaSet$mxTouchDate)/60/60
```

This returns my desired output of:

```
         Leg_ID SeqNum MX_IN_Local_Date_Time MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time RON ROD mxTouch mxTouchDate
1  19W-0001-001      1   2018-02-15 07:29:00    2018-02-15 08:14:00  NA  NA       0    0.000000
2  19W-0001-002      2   2018-02-15 09:34:00    2018-02-15 10:39:00  NA  NA      NA    2.416667
3  19W-0001-003      3   2018-02-15 12:07:00    2018-02-15 13:00:00  NA  NA      NA    4.766667
4  19W-0001-004      4   2018-02-15 14:36:00    2018-02-15 15:21:00  NA  NA      NA    7.116667
5  19W-0001-005      5   2018-02-15 18:03:00    2018-02-15 18:43:00  NA  NA      NA   10.483333
6  19W-0001-006      6   2018-02-15 20:59:00    2018-02-16 06:59:00   1  NA       1   22.750000
7  19W-0001-007      7   2018-02-16 09:40:00    2018-02-16 10:29:00  NA  NA      NA    3.500000
8  19W-0001-008      8   2018-02-16 12:59:00    2018-02-16 13:55:00  NA  NA      NA    6.933333
9  19W-0001-009      9   2018-02-16 16:28:00    2018-02-16 17:10:00  NA  NA      NA   10.183333
10 19W-0001-010     10   2018-02-16 19:45:00    2018-02-16 20:46:00  NA  NA      NA   13.783333
11 19W-0001-011     11   2018-02-16 21:54:00    2018-02-17 08:00:00  NA  NA      NA   25.016667
12 19W-0001-012     12   2018-02-17 09:23:00    2018-02-17 10:25:00  NA  NA      NA   27.433333
13 19W-0001-013     13   2018-02-17 14:58:00    2018-02-17 15:50:00  NA  NA      NA   32.850000
14 19W-0001-014     14   2018-02-17 18:26:00    2018-02-17 20:20:00  NA  NA      NA   37.350000
15 19W-0001-015     15   2018-02-17 23:00:00    2018-02-18 08:25:00   1  NA       1   49.433333
```

Comment: [Please refrain from rolling back edits that remove fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/6296561)

Answer (score 1):

The `lag()` function from the dplyr library is likely what you are looking for. I am going to assume that the previous entry is always the row before it (i.e., the data frame is appropriately sorted).

```
df <- data.frame(val=1:10,other=c(5,5,5,5,NA,5,5,5,5,NA))
df
#    val other
#1    1     5
#2    2     5
#3    3     5
#4    4     5
#5    5    NA
#6    6     5
#7    7     5
#8    8     5
#9    9     5
#10  10    NA

#takes the difference of the current element by the previous one
differences <- df$val - lag(df$val) ## except for the first element, all the differences here should be 1, the first element is NA since there is nothing before it
df$other[is.na(df$other)] <- differences[is.na(df$other)] ## select the differences at the NA values only
df
#    val other
#1    1     5
#2    2     5
#3    3     5
#4    4     5
#5    5     1
#6    6     5
#7    7     5
#8    8     5
#9    9     5
#10  10     1
```

Alternatively, you can do this in base R with `diff()`. The advantage with `lag()` is that it returns a vector of size N when you pass it a vector of size N whereas `diff()` would give you a vector of size N-1. The latter just requires you to make sure your indexes are correct when replacing values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not sure I explained my desired results well enough.  I don't need to reference the previous row, or a static number of previous rows (i.e. row - 3).  It's more of row - x where x is the last row that had a MXTouch.  I have updated my question with a sample of desired results.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#library(zoo)

#convert to timestamp datatype
df$MX_IN_Local_Date_Time <- ymd_hms(df$MX_IN_Local_Date_Time)
df$mxTouchDate <- as.POSIXct(df$mxTouchDate, origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT")

df %>%
  mutate(mxTouchDate_temp = mxTouchDate) %>%
  fill(mxTouchDate_temp) %>%
  #mutate(mxTouchDate_temp = na.locf(mxTouchDate)) %>%
  mutate(sinceLastMxTouch = ifelse((is.na(mxTouch) | mxTouch == 1), as.integer(MX_IN_Local_Date_Time - lag(mxTouchDate_temp)), mxTouch)) %>%
  select(-mxTouchDate_temp)
```

**Output is:**

```
         Leg_ID SeqNum MX_IN_Local_Date_Time MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time RON ROD mxTouch         mxTouchDate sinceLastMxTouch
1  19W-0001-001      1   2018-02-15 07:29:00    2018-02-15 08:14:00  NA  NA       0 2018-02-15 08:14:00                0
2  19W-0001-002      2   2018-02-15 09:34:00    2018-02-15 10:39:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                1
3  19W-0001-003      3   2018-02-15 12:07:00    2018-02-15 13:00:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                3
4  19W-0001-004      4   2018-02-15 14:36:00    2018-02-15 15:21:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                6
5  19W-0001-005      5   2018-02-15 18:03:00    2018-02-15 18:43:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                9
6  19W-0001-006      6   2018-02-15 20:59:00    2018-02-16 06:59:00   1  NA       1 2018-02-16 06:59:00               12
7  19W-0001-007      7   2018-02-16 09:40:00    2018-02-16 10:29:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                2
8  19W-0001-008      8   2018-02-16 12:59:00    2018-02-16 13:55:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                6
9  19W-0001-009      9   2018-02-16 16:28:00    2018-02-16 17:10:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>                9
10 19W-0001-010     10   2018-02-16 19:45:00    2018-02-16 20:46:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>               12
11 19W-0001-011     11   2018-02-16 21:54:00    2018-02-17 08:00:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>               14
12 19W-0001-012     12   2018-02-17 09:23:00    2018-02-17 10:25:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>               26
13 19W-0001-013     13   2018-02-17 14:58:00    2018-02-17 15:50:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>               31
14 19W-0001-014     14   2018-02-17 18:26:00    2018-02-17 20:20:00  NA  NA      NA                <NA>               35
15 19W-0001-015     15   2018-02-17 23:00:00    2018-02-18 08:25:00   1  NA       1 2018-02-18 08:25:00               40
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Leg_ID = c("19W-0001-001", "19W-0001-002", "19W-0001-003", 
"19W-0001-004", "19W-0001-005", "19W-0001-006", "19W-0001-007", 
"19W-0001-008", "19W-0001-009", "19W-0001-010", "19W-0001-011", 
"19W-0001-012", "19W-0001-013", "19W-0001-014", "19W-0001-015"
), SeqNum = 1:15, MX_IN_Local_Date_Time = c("2018-02-15 07:29:00", 
"2018-02-15 09:34:00", "2018-02-15 12:07:00", "2018-02-15 14:36:00", 
"2018-02-15 18:03:00", "2018-02-15 20:59:00", "2018-02-16 09:40:00", 
"2018-02-16 12:59:00", "2018-02-16 16:28:00", "2018-02-16 19:45:00", 
"2018-02-16 21:54:00", "2018-02-17 09:23:00", "2018-02-17 14:58:00", 
"2018-02-17 18:26:00", "2018-02-17 23:00:00"), MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time = c("2018-02-15 08:14:00", 
"2018-02-15 10:39:00", "2018-02-15 13:00:00", "2018-02-15 15:21:00", 
"2018-02-15 18:43:00", "2018-02-16 06:59:00", "2018-02-16 10:29:00", 
"2018-02-16 13:55:00", "2018-02-16 17:10:00", "2018-02-16 20:46:00", 
"2018-02-17 08:00:00", "2018-02-17 10:25:00", "2018-02-17 15:50:00", 
"2018-02-17 20:20:00", "2018-02-18 08:25:00"), RON = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), ROD = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), mxTouch = c(0L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), mxTouchDate = c(1518682440L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1518764340L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1518942300L)), .Names = c("Leg_ID", "SeqNum", "MX_IN_Local_Date_Time", 
"MX_OUT_Local_Date_Time", "RON", "ROD", "mxTouch", "mxTouchDate"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"))
```

Comment: I tried using your solution but was having issues getting `zoo` to load properly.

Comment: You can try to uninstall this package `remove.packages("zoo")` before installing it again `install.packages("zoo")`

Comment: I did.  I work on a network computer, and it gives me fits quite a bit when it comes to installing packages.  Often, I have to take my computer home and install the package then bring it back to work :\

Comment: Not sure if "Proxy" setup in `R` environment can help but it's worth trying - `Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "http://your_network_proxy_url"); Sys.setenv(https_proxy = "http://your_network_proxy_url")`. BTW I have updated my answer to remove dependency on `zoo`package.